В одной из двадцати категориий не отображаются фильтры , как исправить ? eFilter. Evolution cms
Есть сайт на Evolution cms , использую в нём дополнение eFilter для вывода фильтров по категориям. Условно на  20 категориях фильтры eFliter-a  отображаются нормально , а на 21 не отображаются, хотя они точно заданы так же как и в остальных категориях? категории в которых всё работает и та в которой не работает с одним и тем же шаблоном
нет идей куда копать , может кто-то сталкивался и может направить в нужную сторону ?
